# Connection Timed out in Installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and ruby version is: 1.9.3p484

While running the command

sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.18,

I am getting this error

```
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
WARNING:  Error fetching data: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) (http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport-3.2.18.gem)
```

Now when I checked for

```
rvm requirements
```

I am getting the error: **Segmentation fault(core dumped)**

Comment: did you try to rerun the same command again?

Comment: I guess more than 10 times with different versions, and my network is also fine.

Comment: These are two different questions now... Please create s new question in the future, including the original error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Segmentation fault core dump error arises and it's a memory usage problem.This was not a rails problem. So need to format the system. Segmentation fault(core dump): This is the error which comes when a program  try to use the same space which is already filled or try to use the space which is not present.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All those errors seem to come from connection attempts over HTTP, which is deprecated. In your `Gemfile`, the first line is probably

```
source :rubygems
```

you can try to change it to

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: Are you by any chance behind a proxy? You could use the `-p` flag to set the proxy.

Comment: I am behind a proxy and I set up it in my 'bashrc' file as well as 'gemrc' file

Comment: Does it change anything if you pass the proxy server address? `sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.18 -p proxy.example.com`

Comment: manish@manish:~/.rvm/scripts$ sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.18 -p proxy.example.com
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)
    invalid argument: -p proxy.examples.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56049/discussion-between-cyborg-and-p11y).

Comment: Pass the proxy as `http://user:pass@proxy.example.com. Maybe setting up the proxy in your shell helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/47379/how-to-use-a-proxy-on-the-command-line

Comment: The problem was with OS which got solved with re-installing OS, segmentation fault error is with memory so need to format the system. Thanks for help

Comment: @cyborg great! You should write that as an answer and accept it so people see that the question is no longer active.

Comment: I am new user and bcos of lack of point I can't accept that, by the way I have included it in answer.

Comment: Ah I see, sorry didn't notice that.

Comment: hats off to you guys who helps the beginners like us